# Is it possible to use certificate based authentication for the rabbitmq-management plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

We are using the `rabbitmq-management` REST API for different operations on the `rabbitmq`'s entities (queues/exchanges). The standart authentication by login/password works fine, but for some reasons we would like to use password-less authentication (based on ssl certificates). According to the documentation (https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) it looks like there is that possibility.

But if we try to configure the plugin:

**advanced.config**

```
{rabbitmq_management,
  [{listener, [{port,     15671},
               {ssl,      true},
               {ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "c:/Services/certs/cacert.pem"},
                           {certfile,   "c:/Services/certs/cert.pem"},
                           {keyfile,    "c:/Services/certs/key.pem"}]}
              ]}
  ]
}
```

**Our client's .NET app**

```
public Foo(string url, X509Certificate clientCert)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

    _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

    var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri)
 }
```

We get the following (Fiddler session):

1. | Tunnel to | HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established (A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found)
2. | HostName  | HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Is it possible to use certificate based authentication for the `rabbitmq-management` plugin? If Yes, could someone give any samples or a documentation link what we have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently answered this question on the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list: [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/8bP02qvKDUk/lyZIhYVXAAAJ).

The short answer is that you can configure the server to require a client certificate and validate that it was signed by a trusted root cert, but you will still have to provide a username and password - the user won't be extracted from the certificate.